# Do we have to recompile Stored procedure after alterning column length

Tags: database, informix

In our project we have to modify our column length from char(8) to char(10). Now, do we need to recompile any of our stored procedures referring to the table that has this column in question.

FYI the database is informix 11.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you have any procedure variables that must match the column type (length).  If not, then the Informix server will deal with the recompilation automatically.  If you have data types that must be changed to match, then clearly you will need to drop and recreate the procedures after amending the source code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Update related stored procedures. Insert and Updates will work since you increased column size but there can be issues when you select and assign char(10) to  char(8) field. To avoid issues like that you better change all SP's related to this column change.